# Is it possible to share Ghostscript on the network?

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, network-printers

I would like to create a networked Postscript RIP for my Inkjet printer using a Raspberry Pi 4 that isn't getting much use at the moment.

The idea is that my Raspberry Pi 4 should sit on the network as a Postscript printer server, and then it would render the documents and pass them to CUPS for printing on whatever CUPS supported printer I have (it happens to be a colour HP multifunction job, but it works with CUPS).

Ghostscript would appear to be ideal for the task - but how can I get a Postscript document printed over the network into Ghostscript?  Does Ghostscript have a port that it can listen on?  Or should I be using something else?

If this can be made to work, what PPD should I use with Ghostscript?

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript is a Postscript and PDF interpreter/renderer, not a print server. CUPs includes print server capabilities (printer sharing) and ought to be able to handle Postscript print jobs, I would think.

Comment: I know all this.  The question is how can a job be passed to Ghostscript and thence to CUPS for printing.  It may be that it needs to be passed to CUPS which passes it to Ghostscript for interpreting and then back to CUPS for printing.  CUPS can pass postscript to postscript printers for those jobs, I'm asking about whether is can act as a RIP and rastererise for non-postscript printers.

Comment: Like I said in my reply, CUPs includes print server capabilities, and dispatches print jobs to printers via a number of different filters, depending on the capabilities of the printer in question: several of these filters involve Ghostscript, and many don't. CUPs also takes care of things like PPDs.

Comment: When I try CUPS without any additional software, I just get the postscript text printed - not the actual rendered image.

Comment: Well, my guess would be that something is configured wrongly in cups. Basically, I don't think this is a Ghostscript question.